# oauth2-proxy helm kubernetes: ERROR: Failed to initialise OAuth2 Proxy: invalid provider verifier options: missing required setting: issuer-url

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, kubernetes-helm, openid-connect, oauth2-proxy

I had oauth2-proxy running on my Kubernetes cluster which I deployed using Helm via [ArtifactHUB > Helm > OAuth2 Proxy](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy) chart. I just upgraded oauth2-proxy from `v7.1.3` to `v7.4.0` with its chart from `4.2.2` to `6.16.1` and started seeing the following error:

`[main.go:60] ERROR: Failed to initialise OAuth2 Proxy: error intiailising provider: could not create provider data: error building OIDC ProviderVerifier: invalid provider verifier options: missing required setting: issuer-url`

**What is the issue. How to fix it?**

This error is coming on oauth2-proxy `v7.4.0` using default values when configured with Azure AD. It should work without any errors as the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I referred to [OAuth2 Proxy > Docs > Azure Auth Provider](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/configuration/oauth_provider/#azure-auth-provider) from documentation to make it work by adding `azure_tenant` and  `oidc_issuer_url` under `config` in the default values file as follows:

Before:

```yaml
# Oauth client configuration specifics
config:
  configFile: |-
    email_domains = [ "*" ]
    upstreams = [ "file:///dev/null" ]
    http_address = "0.0.0.0:4180"
    provider = "azure"
```

After:

```yaml
# Oauth client configuration specifics
config:
  configFile: |-
    email_domains = [ "*" ]
    upstreams = [ "file:///dev/null" ]
    http_address = "0.0.0.0:4180"
    provider = "azure"
    azure_tenant = "${azure_tenant_id}"
    oidc_issuer_url = "https://sts.windows.net/${azure_tenant_id}/"
```

If it still fails after this change with the following error:

`Error redeeming code during OAuth2 callback: unable to get email and/or groups claims from token: unable to get claims from token: could not initialise claim extractor: failed to parse ID Token: oidc: malformed jwt, expected 3 parts got 1`

then set the `oidc_issuer_url` under `config` in the default values file to V2 Azure Auth endpoint instead as follows:

```yaml
oidc_issuer_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${azure_tenant_id}/v2.0"
```

**NOTE: When using the Azure Auth provider with nginx and the cookie session store, you may find the cookie is too large and doesn't get passed through correctly. Increasing the `proxy_buffer_size` in nginx or implementing the Redis session storage should resolve this.**

*NOTE: `${azure_tenant_id}` will be replaced with the actual Azure App Tenant ID which you can find here: Azure Active Directory (AD) > App registrations > All applications > `[APP NAME]` > Overview > Essentials > `Directory (tenant) ID` where `[APP NAME]` is the name of the registered app for oauth2-proxy.*